# Will workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG) has any effect on workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(TAG, ...)?

Tags: android-workmanager

Previously, we are using the following code, to ensure there will be only one unique worker being enqueued. During that time, `enqueueUniqueWork` API is not available yet.

```
private static void cancelSyncWorker() {
    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(SyncWorker.TAG);
}

public static void startSyncWorker() {
    cancelSyncWorker();

    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, SYNC_WORKER_BACKOFF_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addTag(SyncWorker.TAG)
                    .build();

    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
}
```

Now, we would like to switch over to `enqueueUniqueWork`. We plan to use the following code.

```
private static void cancelSyncWorker() {
    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(SyncWorker.TAG);
}

public static void startSyncWorker() {
    // Cancel the legacy worker queued using legacy workManager.enqueue. 
    // This code shall be removed after some time.
    cancelSyncWorker();

    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, SYNC_WORKER_BACKOFF_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addTag(SyncWorker.TAG)
                    .build();

    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
            SyncWorker.TAG,
            ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            oneTimeWorkRequest
    );
}
```

---

Note, `cancelSyncWorker` is still there, because even user device is upgraded to new app code, the system still has old job which is enqueued via legacy `workManager.enqueue`

The first parameter for `enqueueUniqueWork` is `String uniqueWorkName`.

I was wondering, will calling `workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(SyncWorker.TAG)` has any effect on `workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(SyncWorker.TAG, ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cancelAllWorkByTag(tagname)` cancels all the jobs with that tag associated. Unique workers included if they share the same TAG.

In your code you should add the unique work without a TAG or with a different TAG if you need one. There's an additional set of APIs that you can use to observe/cancel your unique work using its unique worker name.

To handle unique work use:

- [`cancelUniqueWork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#cancelUniqueWork(java.lang.String))
- [`getWorkInfosForUniqueWork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(java.lang.String))
- [`getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(java.lang.String))

Your function can be updated, removing the `addTag` call, becoming:

```
public static void startSyncWorker() {
    // Cancel the legacy worker queued using legacy workManager.enqueue. 
    // This code shall be removed after some time.
    cancelSyncWorker();

    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, SYNC_WORKER_BACKOFF_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();

    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
            SyncWorker.TAG,
            ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,  // Use REPLACE only if necessary, KEEP is less expensive
            oneTimeWorkRequest
    );
}
```

One thing to note, I'm using `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` if there's no particular reason to replace the existing worker (without knowing what/how your worker syncs the data it's difficult to be sure if this is ok). Replacing the worker is a more expensive action and can generate a cancellation of an already executing worker (if you replace it while it's running).

Comment: Extremely useful info. I first though I need to assign same name for unique work and worker (Based on code example). Seem like it is not necessary. Also, thanks for telling me `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` is less expensive. In some cases. Worker will have different `setInputData` content each time. So, I will still stick with `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE`. But, for some cases without `setInputData`, I will use `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP`. Thank you.